# Open URL while passing POST data with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to change the page URL while passing post data to the new page?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, you just want to post to the a new page and load it? post to one page, load another?

Comment: I want to change the current page from MyPage.com/Page1 to MyPage.com/Page2.  At the same time, I would like some POST data passed to Page2

Answer (score 15):

If you mean that you want to change the **current** page URL, well then you can add a new `<form>` to the current page, add hidden input elements to it, and then submit it.

```
$('body').append($('<form/>')
  .attr({'action': yourNewURL, 'method': 'post', 'id': 'replacer'})
  .append($('<input/>')
    .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'param1', 'value': "hello"})
  )
  .append($('<input/>')
    .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'param2', 'value': "world"})
  )
).find('#replacer').submit();
```

Or something similar

Comment: Is it possible to use jQuery.ajax?

Comment: Well if you want to replace the whole page anyway, what's the point of Ajax?

Comment: @Brian - You want to **change pages**, ajax is specifically to prevent **changing pages**.  What you want is a form with an action that goes to the new page, nothing more.  You don't even need a lick of javascript to do this either, just a `<form action="/Page2" method="POST">`

Answer (score 5):

Try the following function. Works for me. JSON compatible.

```
/**
 * Function that will redirect to a new page & pass data using submit
 * @param {type} path -> new url
 * @param {type} params -> JSON data to be posted
 * @param {type} method -> GET or POST
 * @returns {undefined} -> NA
 */
function gotoUrl(path, params, method) {
    //Null check
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    //Fill the hidden form
    if (typeof params === 'string') {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", 'data');
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
    else {
        for (var key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                if(typeof params[key] === 'object'){
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(params[key]));
                }
                else{
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
                }
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Demo usage

```
    <script>
        $('#GotoNextPage').on('submit', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();

            //Make the data
            var sampleData = new Object();
            sampleData.currentPage = 'We are here';
            sampleData.currentUid = 5;

            gotoUrl("actionPage.php", {'cmd':'nextPage', 'data':sampleData});
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you are POSTing data **not** in a form (*because you could simply set the form's action to the current page*) and the data being posted isn't directly related to the content of the next page, you can use the callback function of [jQuery's .post() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to redirect the user:

```
$.post( '/Page2', { 'foo' : 'bar' }, function() {
    window.location.href = '/Page2';
});
```

This seems like an unlikely situation, maybe you could comment with more details about the data being passed and its relation to the content of Page2?

Comment: I am have one form on my page and one form in a jQueryUI dialog box.  I can't submit them both at once, so I am trying to post both of them using serialize to the target page.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the POST data isn't present when page2 loads

Answer (score 1):

Save variables into `$_SESSION` by using jquery post method

### jquery code

```
$.post("save_session.php", { out: output }) .done(function(data) {  
location.href='your_link.php';
});
```

### Php code (save_session.php)

```
$_SESSION["variables"]=$_POST["out"];
```

### Php code (your_link.php)

```
$output=$_SESSION["variables"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is use php session to keep the data in the target page

**AJAX POST**

```
 $(button).click(function(){
    var s_name=$("#txtbox").val(); 
 $.post("http://localhost/AJAX/save_session.php",
{
  student_name: s_name,

},
function(data){

  location.href='http://localhost/AJAX/result.php';
});
```

**Save Session PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"]=$_POST['student_name'];

?>
```

Finally your target page

**targetpage.php**

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  include("config.php");
  $name=$_SESSION["name"];
?>
```

Now you can use the $name or the variable defined to pass the data