# logic change url get to post method jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

I am trying to convert a GET URL to a POST URL in Jquery, I need logical help.

My Code:

```
//Code need to change
var url = '/index.php?page=invoice&action=InvoicePrint&from=print&invoiceid='+Invoiceid;
    window.open(url, "_blank");

//My new code:
var url = '/index.php?page=invoice&action=InvoicePrint&from=print&invoiceid=' + Invoiceid;
            $('<form action="'+url+'" target="_blank"></form>').appendTo('body').submit();
```

1. I cant use GET Method because of the no of invoice ID's (Ex: some 1000 Ids like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7) So I am changing to POST Method to post the Id's.
2. I face problem when I submit by appending a form to body. Check my code above "My new code:". The form was posted to

> index.php?

But It was to be:

> index.php?page=invoice&action=InvoicePrint&from=print&invoiceid=1,2,3,4,5,6,7

But nothing was appended to the URL.

Yes, I tested with same GET Method. Once the URL post works i will convert o POST Method. Because only "incoiceid" I am trying to post all other GET Method remains same.

Thank you

Comment: use different variable names like `o_url` and `url`. You can also use `$.post`

Comment: not helping much in my senario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add method atribute for form, like

```
<form action="'+url+'" method="post" target="_blank"></form>
```

**UPDATED** But you can't store data in your url. Post should send params in body, not in URL. So your url should be like '/index.php'. And your params should be in body, so add all your page, action, etc to form's hidden fields.

```
<form action="/index.php" method="post" target=...>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="InvoicePrint"/>
    ............
</form>
```

or use jQuery post

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/index.php',
   data: data,
   success: success
});
```

Where data is object with all your params

Comment: @Sergay I want to redirect to the next page.. Using ajax i dont think it will work..

Comment: so use form with hidden fields

Comment: Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367594/open-url-while-passing-post-data-with-jquery